# Created symbolic link is not searchable?

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal

I don't know what is wrong here, I just created a symbolic link in my Mac's terminal as follow:

```
sudo ln -s ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/Current/libBLAS.dylib /usr/lib/libatlas.dylib
```

And when I search libatlas.dylib the locate command can't find it:

```
locate libatlas.dylib
```

No results for the locate command. Any hint or remark are welcome. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`locate` doesn't search your file system; it merely reports what it finds in the database refreshed by `updatedb` (which is run periodically by `cron`). Either run `updatedb` manually, or wait until the next time your system runs it. Then `locate` should find the file.

Comment: Thank @chepner, my problem is that the system is not finding this symbolic link, i am now compiling a library that need to use libatals but the compilation tells me that the library is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You presumably want to create an absolute symlink to a library so why the `../..` ?
Symlinks store whatever you give them